# How to prove upper bound for rich-neighbor edge coloring in regular graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, coloring

I'm having difficulty proving a statement in graph theory.
In an edge coloring, an edge $e$ is called $rich$ if all edges adjacent to $e$ have different colors. An edge coloring is called a *rich-neighbour edge coloring* if every edge is adjacent to some rich edge. The smallest number of colors for which there exists such a coloring is denoted by $X_{rn}'(G)$. For example $X_{rn}'(K_4)=6$.

We want to prove the following statement:

> For every $k$-regular graph $G$ where $k \geq 4$, we have $X_{rn}'(G) \leq 2k - 1.$

For now my only idea was to construct a path in $G$ (which has $n$ vertices and is $k$-regular with $k\geq 4$) and choose the first 3 colors to color the path in such a way that I get a rich neighbor edge coloring from the start. Then separate into 3 possible cases according to the congruence class mod 3 of the path’s length, $2n - 1$. Then begins the taking care of other edges that aren’t on the path. At this point I don't know what to do. My ideas are to show that I can either alter the path or something similar if I run out of colors. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion/attempt is not a complete resolution of your problem, but it would allow you to reduce the number of cases to consider, were it to convince you.

Step 1: Prove your statement for the complete k-regular graph $K_{k+1}$.

Step 2 (trivial): Acknowledge that $X'_{rn}(G') \leq X'_{rn}(G)$, for $G'$ a subgraph of $G$.

Step 3: Consider any k-regular graph $G$.  Construct a coloring proving your statement using the result obtained in step 1. This can be done by first considering any $k+1$ vertices $v_1, \dots, v_{k+1}$ in $G$ and coloring any edges of the form $v_iv_j$, $i,j \in \{1, \dots, k+1\}$ in a way that fulfills the requirement (This is possible since $\{v_1,\dots,v_{k+1}\}$ form a subgraph of $K_{k+1}$.

Step 3 (continued): Repeat the following until all edges are colored:

Consider $k$ previously considered vertices and one non-considered one adjacent to any of them. Again, use step 1 to form an appropriate coloring using the same set of $2K-1$ colors previously used.

By formalizing step 3 and proving step 1, you should obtain a solution.

Comment: Although the suggestion seems intreaging, I am having trouble proving step 1 since  I doesn't seem obvious to me, how to always be able to construct a rich-neighbor edge coloring. It's obvius that the lower bound is going to be $2k - 1$, but that;s where It ends for me currently when it comes to promising ideas.